# Using clojure schedulers

Tags: clojure, scheduler

How to evaluate a function correctly every minute using `at-at` and `chime`?

Here are my tests:

```
(require '[overtone.at-at :refer :all]
         '[chime :refer [chime-at]]
         '[clj-time.periodic :refer [periodic-seq]]
         '[clj-time.core :as t])

;; 1. Use of future

(defonce data1 (atom {:num 1}))

(defonce updater
  (future
    (while true
      (swap! data1 update-in [:num] inc)
      (Thread/sleep 60000))))


;; 2. Using at-at

(defonce data2 (atom {:num 1}))

(def my-pool (mk-pool))

(every 60000 #(swap! data2 update-in [:num] inc) my-pool)


;; 3. Using chime

(defonce data3 (atom {:num 1}))

(chime-at (periodic-seq (t/now) (-> 60 t/seconds))
          (fn [] (swap! data3 update-in [:num] inc))
          {:error-handler (fn [e] (str e))})
```

After 5 minutes:

```
@data1
;;=> {:num 5}
@data2
;;=> {:num 8}
@data3
;;=> {:num 1}
```

Why is `at-at` counting to fast?
Why is `chime`not counting at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's up with at-at.

As for Chime, `chime-at` calls the callback function with the time of the current chime, so you'll need to amend your callback to something like

```
(fn [time] (swap! data3 update-in [:num] inc))
```

With `(fn [] …)` you'll get an `ArityException` at each chime and your `:error-handler` swallows those. (Chime's default handler prints a stack trace; NB. depending on your setup that stack trace may or may not be visible in your REPL window – for example with a fairly typical Emacs/CIDER setup you might have to switch to an `*nrepl-server*` buffer to see it.)

(Incidentally, in 1.7 alphas you can use `update :num` instead of `update-in [:num]`.)

Comment: Thank you, it now works perfectly fine. As for `at-at`, I need to add `:fixed-delay true` at the end of the call.